# Apache commons movefile method fails in windows

Tags: scala, playframework, apache-commons

I have a play application. I am using [play-res](https://github.com/digiPlant/play-res) and [play-scalr](https://github.com/digiPlant/play-scalr) libraries for image resizing at server side.
When I am doing multi-part form submission with image file. At server side I get following exception ONLY on windows system NOT on mac.

Stack trace

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'E:\tmp\multipartBody677849053220396275asTemporaryFile' after copy to 'E:\work\projects\rismus\res\profile\268d\3a0d\268d3a0d9a36e7cc8b826b274de4aaa47fdc6591.jpg'
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2835) ~[commons-io.jar:2.4]
    at se.digiplant.res.api.Res$.put(Res.scala:81) ~[play-res_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at se.digiplant.res.api.Res$.put(Res.scala:117) ~[play-res_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at controllers.ImageUploader$$anonfun$upload$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$1.apply(ImageUploader.scala:37) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.ImageUploader$$anonfun$upload$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$1.apply(ImageUploader.scala:36) ~[na:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at controllers.ImageUploader$$anonfun$upload$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ImageUploader.scala:36) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.ImageUploader$$anonfun$upload$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ImageUploader.scala:26) ~[na:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Let me know if It requires more info to understand the issue.

**EDIT**: upload function

```
def upload(accountId: Long): EssentialAction = Authenticated(
    account => Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { request => Future {
        if (account.id != accountId) Results.Unauthorized
        else {

          if (request.body.files.filter(f => !checkFileType(f)).length > 0) {
            BadRequest("Unsupported file type")
          } else {

            val assets = request.body.files.map { file =>
              val assetId = Res.put(file, source, Seq.empty) //fails here
              Map("asset_id" -> assetId, "mime" -> file.contentType.get)
            }

            if (assets.length == 0) BadRequest("No Images uploaded")


            DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
              assets.foreach { asset =>
                  Accounts.updatePicture(accountId, asset("asset_id"))
              }
            }

            Ok(Json.toJson(assets))

          }
        }
      }
    },
    failedResult = Results.Unauthorized
  )
```

Comment: Hi! I'm the creator of play-res and play-scalr. I'm sorry but I don't have a windows machine to test this on. Since I'm using apache commons to do the heavy lifting, moving copying files, it looks like the bug is in there. Let me know if there is anything I can do to make it go away :)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows files are locked while they are open and cannot be deleted. On Unix/Linux, files can usually be deleted while open (except if a network filesystem is involved) - the file still exists on disk, still taking up space, until its last file descriptor is closed, but is detached from the directory so it's not visible.

So the problem is that the temporary file has not been closed yet.

Comment: Ok get it, can you please suggest what's the solution for this, how can I close the temporary file before deleting.

Comment: @pankajmi I looked at the source code and found no bugs. So maybe the bug is in your code, or maybe you are using a different version with a bug. Either way, more details would be helpful.

Comment: I am using version play-scalr 1.0.1, and according to [commit history](https://github.com/digiPlant/play-scalr/commits/) this seems to be the latest. I have edited my question with more code

Comment: @pankajmi Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: I am using Play 2.2.0, scala 2.10